# Washing your Dog

Tags: dogs

Can you use human shampoo for washing your dog?
I don't have pet shampoo and was wondering is it safe to use human shampoo.

Comment: Welcome to pets, thank you for posting your question, but we already have an answer to this one at [Can I use human shampoo to wash a dog?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/can-i-use-human-shampoo-to-wash-a-dog)