# Is it OK to wash my dogs head/face with the hose and dog shampoo?

Tags: dogs, bathing

I feel like I have read that it's a bad choice to wash your dog's head and face, because you could get water in their ears and have their eyes irritated.
What are some options I can try that would avoid these negative things, but still allow me to get my dog fully clean?

Are there different shampoo choices for a dogs head/face that would be better to use than those for a dogs body?

My dog is a 65 lbs (29 kg) Labrador Retriever.

Comment: Related question [Can I use human shampoo to wash a dog?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1938)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good alternative is to get dog bathing wipes and wipe around their face. This way there is no risk of anything getting into their eyes. However, you'd have to check to make sure that there is nothing in them that would irritate your dog. Another alternative would be to get a washcloth or sponge for the dog and only use water or waterless dog shampoo. Source: https://www.pedigree.com/dog-care/health/cleaning-your-dog-s-face-and-eyes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on waterless dog shampoo, I wasn't aware that existed.

Answer (score 0):

My dog hates it, so I feel like a bully if/when I do it, but it hasn't caused any problems. Although, I try to be gentle around the sensitive parts of the face, and only use water, wet wipes, or baby shampoo.

I think I used regular shampoo and conditioner a couple of times, but was concerned it might be sting the eyes when rinsing with water. You can take care how and where you apply the soaps, etc. but water is more difficult to control.

I think this is the one I've used. It came in a container that was more orange/pink, but I think it's basically the same:
[image: no more tears]